# Twitter retweets network in R

Tags: r, graph, package, text-mining

I want to create retweets network - who retweets whom
my code is:

```
library(rtweet)
library(igraph)
library(hrbrthemes)
library(ggraph)
library(tidyverse)
library(ggplo2)
library(dplyr)


brexit.tweets.rt <- search_tweets(
  "#brexit", n = 5000
)
filter(brexit.tweets.rt, retweet_count > 0) %>%
  dplyr::select(screen_name, mentions_screen_name) %>%
  unnest(mentions_screen_name) %>%
  filter(!is.na(mentions_screen_name)) %>%
  graph_from_data_frame() -> rt_g

V(rt_g)$node_label <- unname(ifelse(degree(rt_g)[V(rt_g)] > 20, names(V(rt_g)), "")) 
V(rt_g)$node_size <- unname(ifelse(degree(rt_g)[V(rt_g)] > 20, degree(rt_g), 0)) 
quartz()
ggraph(rt_g, layout = 'linear', circular = TRUE) + 
  geom_edge_arc(edge_width=0.125, aes(alpha=..index..)) +
  geom_node_label(aes(label=node_label, size=node_size),
                  label.size=0, fill="#ffffff66", segment.colour="springgreen",
                  color="slateblue", repel=TRUE, family=font_rc, fontface="bold") +
  coord_fixed() +
  scale_size_area(trans="sqrt") +
  labs(title="Retweet Relationships", subtitle="Most retweeted screen names labeled. Darkers edges == more retweets. Node size == larger degree") +
  theme_graph(base_family=font_rc) +
  theme(legend.position="none")
```

However when I run it i receive number of errors:
Error in grid.Call(C_textBounds, as.graphicsAnnot(x$label), x$x, x$y,  : 
  polygon edge not found
In addition: Warning messages:

> 1: In grid.Call(C_textBounds, as.graphicsAnnot(x$label), x$x,
>   x$y,  :  no font could be found for family "Roboto Condensed" 2: In
>   grid.Call(C_textBounds, as.graphicsAnnot(x$label), x$x, x$y,  :   no
>   font could be found for family "Roboto Condensed" 3: In
>   grid.Call(C_textBounds, as.graphicsAnnot(x$label), x$x, x$y,  :   no
>   font could be found for family "Roboto Condensed" 4: In
>   grid.Call(C_textBounds, as.graphicsAnnot(x$label), x$x, x$y,  :   no
>   font could be found for family "Roboto Condensed" 5: In
>   grid.Call(C_textBounds, as.graphicsAnnot(x$label), x$x, x$y,  :   no
>   font could be found for family "Roboto Condensed"

It may be Arial font problem but my font is installed and is up and running. What are the other possible reasons?

How to fixt that? What about this error with "Roboto Condensed"? I am using mac OS maybe this is OS related?

Any ideas?

Comment: Please include all necessary packages and variables to run your snippet. Maybe you need to register extra fonts with the `extrafont` package (dunno about Mac).

Comment: You have all of the packages I have used. Variables as well.

Comment: `library(ggplo2)` is probably `library(ggplot2)`, and `font_rc <- "Roboto Condensed"`? Have you checked the extrafont package to register extra fonts? I cannot reproduce the missing polygon edge error without your `brexit.tweets.rt` data (maybe share it, too).

Comment: Data are generated with `search tweets` command from rtweets package

Comment: Yes, but I don't get the _error_. And to heal the warnings, I register fonts using extrafonts.

Comment: It fixed a problem! Thank you! Mac os is strange somtimes ;)